# Query SQL SERVER - Doble Condicional

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, mysqli, sql-server-2012

tengo el siguiente problema.

Necesito asignar la fecha a un registro en donde tengo que elegir la menor, y luego seleccionar la mayor dentro de las fechas que son menor.

Para aclarar el problema, por ejemplo tengo la siguiente situación:

Datos de ejemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Movimiento(Cod varchar(3), Cantidad int, Fecha date);
CREATE TABLE dbo.Unitario(Cod varchar(3), Costo int, Fecha date);

INSERT INTO dbo.Movimiento 
VALUES  ('AAA',2,'20180125'),
        ('AAA',3,'20190901'),
        ('AAA',5,'20200401'),
        ('BBB',4,'20200527'),
        ('BBB',4,'20210527');


INSERT INTO dbo.Unitario 
VALUES  ('AAA',200,'20180125'),
        ('AAA',300,'20191231'),
        ('BBB',500,'20191231'),
        ('BBB',1000,'20201231');
```

Cómo puedo asignar el costo Unitario ( tabla Unitario) al código de tabla Movimiento, en donde la fecha del Movimiento debe ser menor o igual a la de la tabla de costo Unitario?

Resultado esperado del ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He estado buenas horas con el problema y aún no se me ocurre una solución. Les agradecería si me ayudan con un par de ideas.

Comment: Buenas, para poder ayudarte, necesitamos ver tu codigo y entender la logica que estás aplicando.

Comment: Mysql o sqlserver? es para quitar las etiquetas que no tienen relación con la pregunta :)

Comment: Estoy probando con ese código que subí

Comment: Pon un ejemplo de lo que esperas obtener, una imagen puede servir, es que tu explicación es algo confusa

Comment: Voy a poner los resultados esperados de la tabla:

Comment: Creo que tu lógica está un poco mal. El costo unitario debería ser el último costo establecido antes de la fecha del movimiento. De otra forma, los movimientos irían cambiando el costo y siempre se reflejaría el mismo para todos.

Comment: El amigo que publico la solución es lo correcto, ya que se debe tomar el costo unitario vigente para la fecha que se demando el producto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esto es sencillo con una instrucción APPLY para solo regresar la primer fila que cumpla con la condición establecida.

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Movimiento m
OUTER APPLY ( SELECT TOP 1 --Usamos OUTER para no perder filas
                     costo --Solo regresamos las columnas necesarias
               FROM  dbo.Unitario u
               WHERE u.Cod = m.Cod --Mismo producto
               AND   u.Fecha >= m.Fecha -- la fecha del Movimiento debe ser menor o igual a la de la tabla de costo Unitario
               ORDER BY u.Fecha DESC) u --Ordenamos de forma descendente para obtener la fecha mayor
```